# Как настраивать I/O ножки микропроцессора ARM Cortex M7 STM32F746

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32

У меня есть отладчик *ST-Link* (SWD интерфейс), плата *Waveshare Core746i* с контроллером **STM32F746**. Как в Atollic Studio (внутри ARM GCC) настроить порты ввода-вывода.
Дайте пожалуйста код на **C/C++**.

Comment: Вряд-ли Вам кто-то ответит предметно на такой слишком конкретный вопрос. Это нужно чтобы человек работал именно сейчас именно с таким же контроллером и к тому же заходил на SO. А вероятность этого очень маленькая. Вам самому надо читать Data Sheet и настраивать порты ввода-вывода.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Настройка портов похожа на всех контроллерах STM, проблема именно  в понимании datasheet. Я нормально понимаю английский, но я только начал разбираться в специфике разработки под ARM.